# Do I need to reason why I use a particular technology in my research proposal?

Tags: research-proposal, tools, technology

I have started doing a research related to NoSQL databases for the master's degree and I have submitted the research proposal.
Proposal evaluation results have been released and the examiner has added some comments.
My question is about one of his comment.
In my research I have mentioned that I am going to use Yahoo! Cloud Serving Benchmark (YCSB) for the evaluation process of the research. The examiner asks me to justify the appropriateness of use of YCSB for the performance assessment.
What does this mean? Does that mean I need to reason all the tools or technologies I have chosen to assist the research process?
The real reason for choosing YCSB is because it has been used in many recent past researches related to NoSQL databases and also there seems to have limited standard available bench marks in the field.

Comment: This isn't a full answer, but for the topline question itself: If the official examiner asks you for something you'd better provide it as they are the gate through which you must pass. Whether that is "logical" or not is irrelevant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two (related) questions:

> 1. What does this mean?

This means you should explain why you suggest using YCSB (You already know the reasoning, given your last sentence.)

> 2. Does that mean I need to reason all the tools or technologies I have chosen to assist the research process?

No. If that were the case, the examiner would have asked you to. In general, researchers use direct/concise language. Do not assume that they actually/secretly want you to answer another question than the one they have asked you.

Comment: I'd add to this: find the original description of this benchmark, understand the creators' purposes in creating it, and cite their paper(s) (conference or journal) or websites or software releases in putting it out there. Summarize their reasoning (don't copy it!) in your justification, and cite it! This will be more persuasive than just a bare statement that the field hasn't provided sufficient benchmarks of databases (SQL and NoSQL) to-date. This statement requires a citation.

Comment: That is a great persuasive solution I didn't think of executing. +1 for that.